# What is the best approach for animating a object in View when using MVVM?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a simple Xamarin Forms app. I am using Prism Forms. I would like to animate Label with basic fade animation in View, when its  old value and new value is not equal. What is the best approach for animating a object in View? Thank you in advance.

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public HomePageViewModel()
    {       
            Title = "First";
            ChangeTitle();
    }

    private async void ChangeTitle()
    {

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        if(Title == "First")
        {
            Title = "Second";
        }
        else
        {
            Title = "First";
        }

        ChangeTitle();
    }



    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

}
```

**MainPage.xml**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="SmapleApp.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    Title="Main Page">

    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It can be done easily with the "Messenger" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center BUT I'd rather do it with a custom control (posted my answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animation logic should be limited to views only. Recommended option would be to use an attached behavior that listens for text changes and accordingly animates the associated label.

```
public class FadingLabelAnimationBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    private Label _associatedObject;

    private uint DesiredDuration { get; set; } = 750;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        _associatedObject = bindable;

        _associatedObject.PropertyChanged += OnTextChangedHandler;
    }

    private async void OnTextChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _associatedObject.Opacity = 0f;
            await _associatedObject.FadeTo(1f, DesiredDuration);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label bindable)
    {
        _associatedObject = null;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        _associatedObject.PropertyChanged -= OnTextChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" ... >
    <Label.Behaviors>
        <local:FadingLabelAnimationBehavior />
    </Label.Behaviors>
</Label>
```

More options to explore:

1. [How do you have UI animations in an MVVM implementation?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42684/how-do-you-have-ui-animations-in-an-mvvm-implementation)
2. [Complex Animations in Xamarin.Forms using Finite State Machine](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/complex-animations-xamarin-forms-using-finite-state-machine/)

Answer (score 2):

The way I would implement it is to create a reusable custom control, which should contain all the logic/animation/xaml. So it should be something like this:

Your Custom control Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestingXamarin.MyCustomText"
             x:Name="mycontrol">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label x:Name="mytext" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Your code-behind of the custom control:

```
public partial class MyCustomText : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomText),
        propertyChanged: async(s, ea, eas) =>
        {
            var myControl = s as MyCustomText;
            var myTextControl = myControl.mytext;
            await myTextControl.FadeTo(0, 100);
            myTextControl.Text = eas.ToString();
            await myTextControl.FadeTo(1, 100);
        });

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MyCustomText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:
Your page:

```
<StackLayout 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="This is my control:"  />
        <myapp:MyCustomText Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <Button Text="Change text" Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Then finally your ViewModel (regardless what framework you use):

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => title;
        set
        {
            if(value != title)
            {
                title = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Command ChangeTextCommand
    {
        get => new Command(() => Title = $"Time Now is {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```